# Toggling State while using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

By default, I want to show the temperature of the current gps location. But if the user wishes to see the temperature of  any other specific country  he can do so by providing the country name.

I have used HomeLocation as the toggle, such that whenever '/' is rendered the HomeLocation is set to `true`, an axios request is made to the api using the Geocoordinates, and if the HomeLocation is set to `false`, an axios request is made using the country name.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import SearchBar from "./components/Dashboard/Searchbar";
import NavBar from "./components/Dashboard/Navlink";
import Weekly from "./components/Weekly/WeeklyDashboard";

function getlocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation not supported");
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Location: "",
      HomeLocation: true,
      ResponseDetails: {
        City: "",
        Country: "",
        Geolocation: "",
      },
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.state.HomeLocation === true) {
      console.log("Make request to open weather api using gps cordinates");
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Make request to open api using the country name provided by the user"
      );
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main">
        <div className="SearchGroup">
          <div>
            <SearchBar />
          </div>

          <div>
            <NavBar />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/"  component={() => <Dashboard WeatherDetails={this.state.ResponseDetails} />} exact />
          <Route path="/:coutryname" component={() => <Dashboard WeatherDetails={this.state.ResponseDetails}/>} />/
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `react-router-dom` [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) so you can get access to objects such as `location` & `history`.

Basically on your `componentWillMount` just check if the location is equal to the home path which is "/" or a specified country provided by the user

```
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {

    ...

    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.location.pathname === "/") {
            console.log("Make request to open weather api using gps coordinates");
        } else {
            console.log("Make request to open api using the country name provided by the user");
        }
    }

    ...
    
}

export default withRouter((props) => <App {...props} />);
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-leaf-ps8ho?file=/src/App.js

---

As a side note, `componentWillMount` is deprecated. You might want to look into using `componentDidMount` instead

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

---

Furthermore, if you need to set the state when your route changes, you can do the route checking on `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    /* check if previous route is different from current route (i.e., if redirected) */
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
        // some logic such as performing axios requests & setting state
    }
}
```